# How to select SVG line xy coordinates using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I there any possible way to change/select `SVG` ***xy*** coordinates using css?
For example:

```
 <svg class="line line-1" width="700" height="500">
    <line x1="120" y1="330" x2="1000" y2="750" stroke="#ffffff"/>
 </svg>
```

> I want to change ***xy*** coordinates whit media query in css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply a translation with CSS to change the coordinates of your line. Here is an example where I made the line to start from `(0,0)`:

```css
svg {
  background:red;
}
svg line {
  transform:translate(-120px,-330px);
}
```

```html
 <svg class="line line-1" width="700" height="500">
    <line x1="120" y1="330" x2="1000" y2="750" stroke="#ffffff"/>
 </svg>
```

And if you will have many elements you can group them inside a `g` orn where you apply the needed transformation as you can also consider rotation, scale, etc:

```css
svg {
  background: red;
}

svg g.coord {
  transform: translate(-120px, -330px);
}
```

```html
<svg class="line line-1" width="700" height="500">
<g class="coord">
    <line x1="120" y1="330" x2="1000" y2="750" stroke="#ffffff"/>
    <line x1="120" y1="330" x2="300" y2="650" stroke="blue"/>
    <line x1="120" y1="330" x2="180" y2="650" stroke="green"/>
</g>
</svg>
```